# How to detect enemies at a larger radius without expanding range where enemies can detect the player?

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I had tried to enlarge the player's collider's radius so that it can detect enemies in a wider range and attack them by shooting. However, it seems like the large collider is also affecting the enemies' ability to detect the player.

How can I make a large radius for the player's remote attack, while keeping the enemies only able to detect an object the size of the player's visible model?

If I add a child object with a trigger collider to detect the attack range, is this a good solution?

[image: Unity capsule surrounded by sphere collider]

Comment: What kind of attack? Shooting? Raycast might give you some ideas.

Comment: I've tried to clarify the question - please feel free to make corrections if I've misunderstood your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of Colliders called hitColliders.

Use the Physics.OverlapSphere() method to find all the colliders within a given range from the current object's position.

Then in use foreach (Collider hitCollider in hitColliders) to detect your enemy

Comment: Specifically you mean [Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc.html), right, since that's the version that requires an array be created in advance?

Comment: Yes, Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc() can be better than Physics.OverlapSphere() in situations where you need to detect a certain number of colliders within a sphere, it avoids the overhead of creating a new array every time the method is called.

Comment: is use OnTriggerStay in child better?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if Unity already has this but you may **create mask**.

You need 2 integers:

1. int ownType ... 1 bit in integer (mask works for 32 objects = 2ˇ32).
2. int mask ... with whom object collide

On collision 1st. check if collision is valid to proceed.

Comment: The Unity way to do this is to use [Layer-Based Collision Detection](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html). Colliders on non-interacting layers won't have their collisions or trigger events processed, so you don't need to manually check the mask in user code. Want to update your answer with a write-up based on that documentation?